# Robot beeping when power set to 0

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on an Arduino Uno robot project for college, I have modified my robot to beep and light up when he bumps into a wall or reverses, my robot works fine except for one very annoying problem, when my robots power is switched to 0 to turn him off he starts to beep as though he is bumping and I have no idea why!

My code:

```
#include <Servo.h>                           // Include servo library

Servo servoLeft;                             // Declare left and right servos
Servo servoRight;

byte wLeftOld;                               // Previous loop whisker values 
byte wRightOld;                              
byte counter;                                // For counting alternate corners

void setup()                                 // Built-in initialization block
{ 
  pinMode(7, INPUT);                         // Set right whisker pin to input
  pinMode(5, INPUT);                         // Set left whisker pin to input  
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);                        // Left LED indicator -> output
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);                        // Right LED indicator -> output   

  tone(4, 3000, 1000);                       // Play tone for 1 second
  delay(1000);                               // Delay to finish tone

  servoLeft.attach(13);                      // Attach left signal to pin 13 
  servoRight.attach(12);                     // Attach right signal to pin 12

  wLeftOld = 0;                              // Init. previous whisker states
  wRightOld = 1;  
  counter = 0;                               // Initialize counter to 0
}  

void loop()                                  // Main loop auto-repeats
{

  // Corner Escape

  byte wLeft = digitalRead(5);               // Copy right result to wLeft  
  byte wRight = digitalRead(7);              // Copy left result to wRight

  if(wLeft != wRight)                        // One whisker pressed? (Output on the left is not the same as the right)
  {                                          // Alternate from last time?
  tone(4, 3000, 1000);                       // Beep for 1 second as we hit the wall (BK)
    if ((wLeft != wLeftOld) && (wRight != wRightOld))  
    {                                       
      counter++;                             // Increase count by one
      wLeftOld = wLeft;                      // Record current for next rep
      wRightOld = wRight;
      if(counter == 4)                       // Stuck in a corner?
      {
        wLeft = 0;                           // Set up for U-turn
        wRight = 0;
        counter = 0;                         // Clear alternate corner count
      }
    }  
    else                                     // Not alternate from last time
    {
      counter = 0;                           // Clear alternate corner count
    }
  }  

  // Whisker Navigation 
  if((wLeft == 0) && (wRight == 0))          // If both whiskers contact
  {
    bump();                                  // Call bump function
    backward(1000);                          // Back up 1 second
    reverseBeep();                           // Call reverseBeep function
    turnLeft(800);                           // Turn left about 120 degrees
  }
  else if(wLeft == 0)                        // If only left whisker contact
  {
    bump();                                  // Call bump function
    backward(1000);                          // Back up 1 second
    reverseBeep();                           // Call reverseBeep function
    turnRight(400);                          // Turn right about 60 degrees
  }
  else if(wRight == 0)                       // If only right whisker contact
  {
    bump();                                  // Call bump function
    backward(1000);                          // Back up 1 second
    reverseBeep();                           // Call reverseBeep function
    turnLeft(400);                           // Turn left about 60 degrees
  }
  else                                       // Otherwise, no whisker contact
  {
    forward(20);                             // Forward 1/50 of a second
  }
}

void forward(int time)                       // Forward function
{
  servoLeft.writeMicroseconds(1700);         // Left wheel counterclockwise
  servoRight.writeMicroseconds(1300);        // Right wheel clockwise
  delay(time);                               // Maneuver for time ms
}

void turnLeft(int time)                      // Left turn function
{
  servoLeft.writeMicroseconds(1300);         // Left wheel clockwise
  servoRight.writeMicroseconds(1300);        // Right wheel clockwise
  delay(time);                               // Maneuver for time ms
}

void turnRight(int time)                     // Right turn function
{
  servoLeft.writeMicroseconds(1700);         // Left wheel counterclockwise
  servoRight.writeMicroseconds(1700);        // Right wheel counterclockwise
  delay(time);                               // Maneuver for time ms
}

void backward(int time)                      // Backward function
{
  servoLeft.writeMicroseconds(1300);         // Left wheel clockwise
  servoRight.writeMicroseconds(1700);        // Right wheel counterclockwise
  delay(time);                               // Maneuver for time ms
}

void bump()                                  // Light and sound code for when the robot bumps a wall (BK)
{

  tone(4, 3000, 1000);                       // Play tone for 1 second
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);                     // Left LED on
  digitalWrite(8, LOW);                      // Left LED off

}

void reverseBeep()                           // Light and sound code for when the robot reverses(BK)
{

      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {

        digitalWrite(8, HIGH); // Left LED on
        tone(4, 1600, 400);                     // Beep (Pin 4, 1600Khz tone for 400ms) (BK)
        digitalWrite(8, LOW); // Left LED off

      }

}
```

I am using this breadboard setup
http://learn.parallax.com/tutorials/robot/shield-bot/robotics-board-education-shield-arduino/chapter-5-tactile-navigation-6

The custom functions `bump()` and `reverseBeep()`are my custom functions to control the bumping and reversing beep and LED light up.

Does anyone know why he beeps when the power switch is set to 0?

Comment: Can you share your schematic too?

Comment: Probably electrical schema would be useful too. Servos and motors need high current to move decently fast, while Arduino does not need so much for "just live". If you have there large capacitors, or if the robot is moving when powered off and so turns motors to dynamos temporaly, then it is possible, that even with switch OFF the Arduino have enought power to live for a moment and at the same time the whiskers go donw as if pressed, so it works like it bumped.

Comment: I have edited my question now to include the relevant breadboard diagram.

Comment: Please avoid linking to your code on pastebin as the current configuration will remove your code in less than one month, making your question and any answers just plain useless at that time. Rather copy your code here in your question.

Comment: Code is very large, over 100 lines.

Comment: 100 lines is nothing. 10,000,000 is very large.

Comment: I see no power switch on that diagram. We need your *actual* setup, not someone else's sketch that is vaguely similar in a few ways. How exactly do you "set the power switch to 0"?

Comment: I am following the tutorial, that is the tutorial, that is what I am told to do, the Arduino Uno board has a power switch directly built in http://learn.parallax.com/tutorials/robot/shield-bot/robotics-board-education-shield-arduino/chapter-3-assemble-and-test-12

Comment: Do you have the Arduino wired over USB? You can try logging the whisker statusses and if your bot wants to go left/right. Though your code seems sane and I think it's something electrically.

Comment: It does the same thing if wired or on USB, I probably should have tested another robot, it isn't a big deal it is just a little annoying.

Comment: bill it as a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By beeping I assume you mean a 1 second been with no flash from the LED.
The only place in you code that can happen is when the whiskers are not equal.  I think the whiskers are powered by the shield you have turned off, in which case I suspect they are floating.  Is it possible to power these direct from the board, bypassing the off switch?

The easiest way to fix it would be to allow the processor to know when the Off switch is on and off.  Wire the 5V from the shield to the Arduino via a resistor of ???Ohms and read that pin before doing anything in loop().